# How to obtain the optimal Lagrange multiplier vectors if the globally optimal solution for a nonconvex QCQP is found?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker, qcqp

I am using a black-box solver to solve the following non-convex QCQP to global optimality.

$$ \min_x x^TQ_0x + c^T x \\
s.t. \quad x^TQ_1x+c_1^Tx=b_1 \\
Ax=b \\
l\leq x\leq u
$$

where $Q_0$ is indefinite diagonal matrix and $Q_1$ is positive semidefinite diagonal matrix. 
I have obtained a globally optimal solution of the the above program, say $x^*$. How can I calculate the optimal dual multipliers associated with the constraints? I am thinking of using the KKT conditions, will that be right? The Lagrange dual I am referring to is formulated as 
$$
\max_{\lambda,\nu,\omega,\mu} \min_{x \in \mathbb R^n} L(x,\lambda,\nu,\omega,\mu) \\
\lambda \geq 0, \omega \leq 0, \mu \geq 0 \\ 
L(x,\lambda,\nu,\omega,\mu) = x^TQ_0x+c_0^Tx+\sum_{k=1}^m \lambda_k(x^TQ_kx+c_k^Tx-b_k)+ \sum_{p=1}^q \nu_p(a_p^Tx-b)+\omega^T(x-l)+\mu^T(x-u) 
$$
Upon fixing $x$ to $x^*$ the Lagrange function becomes :
$$
(x^*)^TQ_0x^*+c_0^Tx^*+\omega^T(x^*-l)+\mu^T(x^*-u) 
$$
The first order conditions are $\nabla{L_x}|_{x=x^*}=0$.
The constraints are all satisfied since $x^*$ is an optimal solution
I also think the only possible non-zero multipliers are $\lambda_k$ and $\nu_p$ (from complimentary slackness). Are these conditions sufficient to find the optimal multiplier vector? What is the second order condition here? $Q_0 \succeq 0$? Is second order condition necessary to guarantee global optimality?

Comment: It seems to me that the least you could do is offer us the dual :-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant Sir I have made the change. Hope you can now help me.

Comment: Ah, but here's the thing: *you know the value of $x$!* So how does that simplify your expression for the dual, and how you would solve it?

Comment: (I cannot answer now, but perhaps after work, sorry!)

Comment: @MichaelGrant Sir I have made an edit upto the best of my understanding. Please guide me from their. Thanks !